# Magento 2 : How to setup multiple magento setup using docker?

Tags: magento2

Using this Magento 2 Docker to Development
https://github.com/echo-magento/docker-magento2

This works for one magento setup.

Is their any way if more then one magento setup can be installed with it ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?